# Dynamic class/interface in Typescript (w Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I create an object with a dynamic class by param. Is there a way to specify also the type of that object to have the intellisense?

This is the code:

Main:

```
let ita: any = new DynamicClass('ITA');
let deu: any = new DynamicClass('DEU');
```

Class to create the dynamic class:

```
export class DynamicClass {
  constructor(className: string) {
    if (Store[className] === undefined || Store[className] === null) {
      throw new Error(`Class type of \'${className}\' is not in the store`);
    }
    return new Store[className];
  }
}
```

And my classes:

```
export class ITA {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  pck: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('ITA class');

    this.id = '1';
    this.name = 'ita';
    this.pck = '4';
  }
}

export class DEU {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  size: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('DEU class');

    this.id = '1';
    this.name = 'ita';
    this.size = '5';
  }
}

export const Store: any = {
  ITA,
  DEU,
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what's the use case and why do you need such wrapper?

Comment: I have a localization code as input in a component, and I'd like to create dynamically an object based on that localization code.

Comment: Do the objects you intend to create need to have different types (different fields, methods etc) or they can be of same type?

Comment: @Lesiak they should be different. Different fields, methods etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it:

```
let ita: ITA = new DynamicClass('ITA') as ITA;
let deu: DEU = new DynamicClass('DEU') as DEU;
```

Comment: Yeah man I know it, but I don't want to do it. I'd like to specify the type dynamically, and not hard coded.

Comment: That's not possible. How would that even work? Your IDE would have to predict the future to figure out the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could create factory function which will accept only known class names and its return type will be resolved according to provided key (class name):

```
const Store = {
    ITA,
    DEU,
} as const;

type ClassMap = typeof Store;

const createClass = <Key extends keyof ClassMap>(key: Key) =>
    new Store[key] as InstanceType<ClassMap[Key]>;

const instance = createClass('ITA'); // instance is of ITA type

createClass('foo'); // Error: '"foo"' is not assignable to '"ITA" | "DEU"'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-AARlYUxBSy4S3AAD5wEsHStAA)

Comment: Can it be done without casting in the factory function? If not, why?

Comment: Because `key` is union of all possible class names, so without type assertion the resolved return type will be union of all possible instance types

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
export const Store = {
  ITA,
  DEU,
};

let ita = new Store['ITA'];        // ita type inferred to ITA
let deu = new Store['DEU'];        // deu type inferred to DEU
let x = new Store['MISSING_PROP']; // does not compile
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=68#code/AQYwNghgzlwJIBUCCwDeBYAUMYBLAJgFzBQAuATrgHYDmA3FjlRALYCmxZltD2wADiADWnCtXpZGoAPZUuAVxClp5ABQBKNFJwhZUaWDYA6MNJqqA5IhThoUC%20t7bgpABa4oRgsAC8wCwCMFrw4OG4eRszsvv64pBDBzuGegkIxFgAsiXwAvlh5mIy2MMAAIgCiAKpafASi3BJ8URwkYjxSULgAXi1c4k58unIUispqmhh8OnoGxqbmFhXVxfaOklMu7p7efoHZoZsRzelxCSGhyUadPekArPvABQVFeqTAAMpjbDGTONYANFIloDMDkBoY3qcYlQ2AB3D5fADaVmQFgAurwIcB8Gx5NC4QiVGxkUt0Zi2G8AB74%20GfInIgCycHe7zgADkAOIAfQACgAlADyPLJ6yAA)

but I see no benefit over:

```
let ita = new ITA();
let deu = new DEU();
```

**Update (after clarifying question)**

Why don't you define union type for acepted languages, and use a switch statement:

```
type Langs = 'ITA' | 'DEU'

function doSth(lang: Langs): string { 
  switch (lang) {
    case 'ITA':
      const ita = new ITA();
      return ita.name;
    case 'DEU':
      const deu = new DEU();
      return deu.name + deu.size;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using switch or if is the "standard" way. In the future, when I'll add other countries, I have to modify a lot of code. I'm searching for a dinamically way to create object, even I have only to create the interface for the new country.

Comment: If that is your concern, then you should program against a common interface of these classes.